# how to set image view color as textfield background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

In my home page I added an image to the view and also added textfield over the imageview. I want to show the image color as textfield back ground color
[image]

Comment: set the background color of the textfield to clear color in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Just call:

```
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

> set ClearColor of your textfield's background color in storyboard